# I keep getting the show action instead of a custom action when using a nest route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup isn't too complex I think, I have an Event with some RSVPs.  My routes file has

```
map.resources :events, :has_many => :rsvps
map.resources :rsvps, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy, :index], :collection => { :list => :get }
 map.resources :events do |event|
event.resources :rsvps, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy, :index], :collection => { :list => :get }
      end
```

Which give me a rake routes

> ```
>                     event_rsvps GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  POST   /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                   new_event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                  edit_event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id/edit(.:format)      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                       event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  PUT    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  DELETE /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                           events GET    /events(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  POST   /events(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"events"}
>                        new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"events"}
>                       edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"}
>                            event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"events"}
>                       list_rsvps GET    /rsvps/list(.:format)                           {:action=>"list", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                            rsvps GET    /rsvps(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  POST   /rsvps(.:format)                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                         new_rsvp GET    /rsvps/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                             rsvp DELETE /rsvps/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                 list_event_rsvps GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/list(.:format)          {:action=>"list", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  POST   /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  DELETE /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"rsvps"}
>                                  GET    /events(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  POST   /events(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  GET    /events/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  GET    /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"events"}
>                                  DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"events"}
> ```

I then have a

```
<%= link_to 'List Attending', list_event_rsvps_path(event) %>
```

But when I click this view I get

> Unknown action
>
> No action responded to show. Actions: create, current_admin,
>   current_admin=, destroy, index, list, new, sign_in, sign_out, and
>   signed_in?

the server log shows

> Processing RsvpsController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-10 16:12:18)
>   [GET]   Parameters: {"id"=>"list", "event_id"=>"1"}
>
> ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions:
>   create, current_admin, current_admin=, destroy, index, list, new,
>   sign_in, sign_out, and signed_in?):
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
>
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`run'
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
>
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
>
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
>
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
>
>   c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'

At this point I've tried everything I could find about the subject.  I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and Rail 2.3.18 since my web host is using that still.  I have no clue why it's still looking for the show action when I've removed it from the controller and all the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are applied in the order they are defined. Try putting:

```
map.resources :events, :has_many => :rsvps
```

Below the other routes.

Comment: Well son of a bitch that worked.  Thank you very much.